# Django user images - how to get around this circular dependency?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a circular dependency between two models, `userprofile` and `image`:

- The user profile has a foreignkey to an image of the user
- The image has a foreignkey to the user profile to indicate the owner of that image

This is the error shown when running `makemigrations`:

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 241, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: profiles.0001_initial, media.0001_initial
```

What's a clean way to get around this? (I would prefer to keep images associated with the user profile rather than auth user so that ownership of the user profile and all media can be easily transferred if that's ever necessary)

Here is the actual code (`Lessor` is the user profile):

`profiles.models`

```
class Lessor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
    logo = models.ForeignKey('media.Image', related_name='logo_set', null=True)
    portrait = models.ForeignKey('media.Image', related_name='portrait_set', null=True)
```

`media.models`

```
class Image(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('profiles.Lessor')
```

Comment: The cleanest way would be that only your Image field has a ForeignKey to the Lessor model, instead of both of them have a FK to each other.

Comment: Oh then I may be going after the wrong cause of the error then, please take a look I've updated the OP. I thought this was the problem, but it may be something else.

Comment: Is the owner of the image a different person from the person the image is a portrait of?

Comment: @DanielRoseman they are the same. But there are also images of other things that are not the portrait in that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the `Lessor.portrait` foreign key, and create migrations for both models.

Once the `Image` model has been created, you can uncomment the field, and create a another migration to add the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you please explain why/how that is?

Comment: Django can't create foreign keys for both models at once, because then both migrations both depend on each other and you have a circular dependency. By adding one foreign key at a time you break the circular dependency.